# Cannot instantiate InterfaceController

Tags: objective-c, apple-watch

On a Apple Watch app, I am trying to instantiate a class (InterfaceController) to access a method (method A) in it.
I wrote below code.

```
#import "InterfaceController.h"

- (IBAction)buttonAction {

    InterfaceController *interfaceController =[[InterfaceController alloc] init];
    [interfaceController methodA];

}
```

When I build it and run it, it stops at the line of " InterfaceController *interfaceController =[[InterfaceController alloc] init];" and it says:

> Thread1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1, address=0x10)

Would you advise how to fix it?

------------------------------(added below later)--------------------------

Based on a suggestion, I tried declaring interfaceController as a property
as below but the same result.

```
#import "InterfaceController.h"

@property InterfaceController *interfaceController;

-(IBAction)buttonAction{
    _interfaceController =[[InterfaceController alloc] init];
    [_interfaceController resetMatch];
    [self popController];
}
```

I tried declaring the property in the header file, but it did not work either.

Comment: You should probably create a property for InterfaceController, not just a local variable.

Comment: I tried it but the same result... Pls see my updated question for how I did it. I will appreciate your further support.

Comment: You should add an exception breakpoint to see what line causes the error.

Comment: It stops at the line of "_interfaceController =[[InterfaceController alloc] init];" with the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't create interface objects directly on WatchKit, you have to create them in your storyboard and connect them to your app using IBOutlets.  Declare the controller in your code as an IBOutlet like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet InterfaceController *interfaceController;
```

The add an Interface Controller to your storyboard, change its class name if necessary, and connect it to that outlet.